# scrollview moves up for one uitextfield but not others

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a bunch of textfields relating to an address in my view.  When the user selects one of the bottom 3 textfields the view needs to scroll up to let the user see the textfield, otherwise it's hidden beneath the keyboard.

Here they are:

[image: textfields]

When the user clicks on the Latitude textfield it correctly moves up from beneath the keyboard:

[image: correct movement]

However, when the user clicks on either the country textfield the view does not move at all (admittedly the textfield is only partially covered by the keyboard.  When the user clicks on the Longitude textfield the view scrolls up a small amount, but not nearly enough.  Here they are:

User clicks on country:
[image: clicks on country]

User clicks on longitude:
[image: clicks on longitude]

I am following Apple's [recommended](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7) way of moving the view.  I have basically the exact same code as in listing 5-1 and 5-2 on the docs page.  Has anyone else run into this?  It's rather frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the Contentsize height of the scrollview

Comment: It's so odd to me that this is actually the answer.  The scrollview contains a uiview that has all of the elements.  Making the uiview taller worked.